# python undefined method `import' for main:Object

Tags: python, import, lapack

After messing around with Python this evening I've managed to get the error message in the title.

I'm new to Python so I wasn't expecting to master it overnight but somehow I've managed to break the most rudimentary feature.

The last thing that happened before it broke was installing Lapack.

Running Windows 10, Python 2.7

Any advice? Hoping not to have to uninstall and start again.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm impressed! Are you using the standard Python distribution? If so, I would recommend Anaconda, which bundles a lot of the common scientific computing packages (i.e. scipy, numpy), and takes the pain out of the (sometimes) complex install process for a lot of these packages.

Comment: And I'm pretty sure Lapack can be installed via the conda package manager.

Comment: @AndrewGuy Cheers, man I'm getting Anaconda on the go just now. In the end I just ran pip install sys, it didn't work but it fix the issue...